# Principal curvature of rotating surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from 294 page of
*Huisken, Gerhard*, Asymptotic behavior for singularities of the mean curvature flow, J. Differ. Geom. 31, No.1, 285-299 (1990). [ZBL0694.53005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0694.53005).

I don't understand the notation $y$. If it is a graph, it should be ordered pairs liking $(x,y(x))$. But if so, I can't understand $y^{-1}$. If $y$ just be $y(x)$, then , we can't represent  this rotating surface, just have a curve.  how to understand it ?

Besides, what is the mean of $p,q$ ? How to calculate  1 ?

[image]

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Once you have the surface $M$, for any $\bf x\in M$ you have $y({\bf x})=Distance({\bf x},x_1-axis)$.

Comment: @san  Thanks, do you know how to calculate $\nabla_1 y =-qy$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand well,  (I'm not sure about muy first comment, either), according to my understanding, I have $\nabla_1y=-q/p$.

Comment: @san  From the below of this paper, it should be $\nabla_1 y =-qy$. Could you talk about how to get $\nabla_1y=-q/p$ ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood $\nabla_1 y$, I thought it was $\nabla_{\iota_1}y$, but it seems to be $\nabla_{e_1}y$. In that case the formula seems to be ok. You should work with $qy$ and $py$ instead of $q$, then the formulas are geometrically clear.

Comment: @san  Thanks, what is the geometric mean of the formulas ?

Comment: Well, I only thought about $\nabla_{e_1}y=-qy$. Assume $y'<0$. If you set your point in $x_3=0$, then $qy$ is by definition the lower cathetus of a rightangled triangle, with hypotenuse $\nu$. It has the same length as the triangle formed by $e_1$ (as hypotenuse),  and since $y$ in this picture is simply the height, the directional derivative of $y$ with respect to $e_1$ is the first component of $e_1$, which is $-qy$.

Comment: @san I don't know whether I understand you well. I draw a picture in my qustion above. But I still have some question. First, why $qy$ has the same length as the triangle formed by $e_1$ ?   Second, $y$ is a function of one variable, what is its directional derivative respect to a 2-dim vector ?

Comment: If you rotate your triangle 90 degrees to the right, the hypotenuse is $e_1$ and the vertical cathetus is $qy$, in my (very basic) understanding of differential geometry this means $\nabla_{e_1}y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial e_1}=-qy$.

Comment: @san $y$ is a scalar function, so $\nabla_{e_1}y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial e_1}$ (if the RHS means directional derivative). But I can't understand why $\frac{\partial y}{\partial e_1}=-qy$ ?

Comment: We have $e_1=(py,-qy)$, since the vector $\nu=(qy, py)$ is just $e_1$ rotated 90°.